# Level Order Traversing c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement Level Order Traversal of BT

```
class Node
{
    public int data;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        right = null;
        left = null;
    }
}

unsafe class BinaryTree
{
    Node root;       
    public BinaryTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public void display(Node level)
    {
        Node current = level;
        if (current.left != null)
        {
            display(current.left);              
        }
        Console.WriteLine(current.data);
        if(current.right!=null)
        {
            display(current.right);                
        }
    }

    Queue<int> qu = new Queue<int>();

    public void LevelOrderTraversal()
    {

    }

    public void insert(int num)
    {
        Node newnode = new Node(num);
        Node currentNode;
        if(root==null)
        {
            root = newnode;
        }
        else 
        {
            currentNode=root;
            while(true)
            {
                Node tmpParent = currentNode;
                if(newnode.data<=currentNode.data)
                {
                    currentNode = currentNode.left;
                    if (currentNode == null)
                    { tmpParent.left = newnode; return; }
                }
                else if(newnode.data>currentNode.data)
                {
                    currentNode = currentNode.right;
                    if (currentNode == null)
                    { tmpParent.right = newnode; return; }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BinaryTree bTree = new BinaryTree();
        bTree.root = new Node(50);
        bTree.root.left = new Node(25);
        bTree.root.right = new Node(75);
        bTree.insert(22);
        bTree.insert(78);

        bTree.LevelOrderTraversal(&bTree.root); //Problem occurs here                    
        Console.WriteLine(bTree.root);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

I am trying to pass the address of the root node so that i can add it to the queue but am not sure how to pass the address of the root and capture it at the function. It says address cant take the address of a managed type. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to use pointers in the first place? Why not keep this all managed?

Comment: `unsafe` and the unsafe reference (`&`) are completely not needed here...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. I figured out. Here is the answer

```
class Node
{
    public int data;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        right = null;
        left = null;
    }
}

class BinaryTree
{
    Node root;       
    public BinaryTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public void display(Node level)
    {
        Node current = level;
        if (current.left != null)
        {
            display(current.left);              
        }
        Console.WriteLine(current.data);
        if(current.right!=null)
        {
            display(current.right);                
        }
    }

    Queue<Node> qu = new Queue<Node>();

    public void LevelOrderTraversal()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (qu.Count == 0)
            { return; }
            else
            {
                Node current = qu.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine(current.data);
                if (current.left != null)
                    qu.Enqueue(current.left);
                if (current.right != null)
                    qu.Enqueue(current.right);
            }
        }
    }

    public void insert(int num)
    {
        Node newnode = new Node(num);
        Node currentNode;
        if(root==null)
        {
            root = newnode;
        }
        else 
        {
            currentNode=root;
            while(true)
            {
                Node tmpParent = currentNode;
                if(newnode.data<=currentNode.data)
                {
                    currentNode = currentNode.left;
                    if (currentNode == null)
                    { tmpParent.left = newnode; return; }
                }
                else if(newnode.data>currentNode.data)
                {
                    currentNode = currentNode.right;
                    if (currentNode == null)
                    { tmpParent.right = newnode; return; }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BinaryTree bTree = new BinaryTree();
        bTree.root = new Node(50);
        bTree.root.left = new Node(25);
        bTree.root.right = new Node(75);
        bTree.insert(22);
        bTree.insert(78);
        bTree.qu.Enqueue(bTree.root);
        bTree.LevelOrderTraversal();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```